# HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync using private members instead of public properties

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a client that is POSTing to a Web API. When the POST content is received the JSON is using the private member names for properties instead of the public properties.  (the Client app is using the Asp.Net-Web-api2 library and the Web API itself is implemented using an IHttpHandler on IIS7.5 and is not a MVC style app, also the code was working with the existing Usage class prior to a TFS mishap which caused me to recode and now the odd behavior)

```
//Object I am passing  
[Serializable]
public class Usage
{  
   private string _user;  
   private string _trackingUnit;  

   public string User {get {return _user;} set {_user = value;}}  
   public string TrackingUnit { get{return _trackingUnit;} set { _trackingUnit = value;}}
}
```

I make the post using the following

```
Usage usage = new Usage();  
usage.User = "pete";
usage.TrackingUnit = "unit of work";

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, usage);
```

I am receiving the POST using the following

```
byte[] postData = context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.ContentLength);
string strData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(postData);
Usage newUsage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Usage>(strData);
```

When I examine the strData it looks like the following, which causes the Deserialization to return an unpopulated Usage object

```
{"_user":"pete","_trackingUnit":"unit of work"}
```

I would expect

```
{"User":"pete","TrackingUnit":"unit of work"}
```

Notes:

If i new up a new Usage object and try to Serialize it inside the Web API and return the string it is formatted correctly

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usage);

{"User":"pete","TrackingUnit":"unit of work"}
```

Also if I try to JsonConvert.Serialize in the client application it also works as expected

Comment: How do you initialize "usage" object before posting it ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that would be used.

Comment: Two things you could try: 1) Check your default JSON serializer. 2) Since you can successfully serialize with the `Netwonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Serialize` you could construct your own `HttpRequestMessage` and use `SendAsync()` instead.

Comment: @Jasen , had I not gotten to the root issue (thank you dbc!), that would have been a great workaround, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The reason** you are seeing this is is that your framework uses [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) for JSON serialization, and somewhere in the code base the option [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm) has been set to `false`.  When this setting, Json.NET will serialize the public and private *fields* of a type marked as `[Serializable]` -- which yours is.

To confirm where this is happening we can check the reference source.  Firstly, [`HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync<T>()`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs#L52) serializes to JSON using a freshly constructed `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return client.PostAsync(requestUri, value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), cancellationToken);
}
```

It's base class [`BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs) in turn has an internal `IContractResolver _defaultContractResolver` of type [`JsonContractResolver`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonContractResolver.cs) which, in its constructor, sets

```
// Need this setting to have [Serializable] types serialized correctly
IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false;
```

So that's the source of your problem.

**Your options** to work around this problem are as follows.

Firstly, if you are willing to add a Json.NET dependency to your models, you could mark your type with [`[JsonObject]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm)

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject]
public class Usage
{  
    private string _user;  
    private string _trackingUnit;  

    public string User {get {return _user;} set {_user = value;}}  
    public string TrackingUnit { get{return _trackingUnit;} set { _trackingUnit = value;}}
}
```

This overrides `[Serializable]` by resetting [`JsonObjectAttribute.MemberSerialization`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute_MemberSerialization.htm) to its default value [`MemberSerialization.OptOut`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MemberSerialization.htm).

Secondly, you could annotate your type with [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts), which Json.NET respects:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class Usage
{  
    private string _user;  
    private string _trackingUnit;  

    [DataMember]
    public string User {get {return _user;} set {_user = value;}}  
    [DataMember]
    public string TrackingUnit { get{return _trackingUnit;} set { _trackingUnit = value;}}
}
```

Note that data contract serialization is opt-in so you will need to annotate every member to be serialized.

Thirdly, you could remove `[Serializable]` -- but in your question you indicate that's not an option.

Finally, you could make your own extension methods based on the [reference source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpClientExtensions.cs) that replace those in [`HttpClientExtensions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions(v=vs.118).aspx) and serialize your object with `IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true`, e.g. (not tested):

```
public static class MyHttpClientExtensions
{
    static JsonMediaTypeFormatter CreateJsonMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        var JsonMediaTypeFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        // Use the provided JsonContractResolver but reset IgnoreSerializableAttribute
        ((DefaultContractResolver)JsonMediaTypeFormatter.SerializerSettings).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
        return JsonMediaTypeFormatter;
    }

    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyPostAsJsonAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return client.PostAsync(requestUri, value, CreateJsonMediaTypeFormatter(), cancellationToken);
    }       

    // Replace other JSON methods as required.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, both #1 and #2 suggestions resolve the issue, I'm going with the DataContract route. I very much appreciate the explanation around the solution, just started playing in this area. I didn't test #3 yet but will give it a try as well when I get a chance.